# C++ recv() problem

Tags: c++, sockets

I want to send a string "Hello there", but I only get "re". Why is that?

```
void Accept()
{
    SOCKADDR_IN sock;
    int intsock = sizeof(sock);
    remoteSocket = ::accept(desc, (LPSOCKADDR)&sock,  &intsock);
    if(remoteSocket == -1)
    {
        cout << "Error in Accept()" << endl;
    }
    HandleConnection();
}

void HandleConnection()
{
    cout << "You are connected !!!" << endl;
    char* temp = new char[20];
    Recv(temp);
    cout << temp << endl;
}

void Send(const char* buffer)
{
    if((::send(remoteSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0)) < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error in Send()" << endl;
    }
}

void Recv(char* buffer)
{
    int n = 0;
    while((n = ::recv(remoteSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0)) 0)
    {
        buffer[n] = 0;
    }
}

~Server()
{
    WSACleanup();
}

};

int main()
{
    Server s;
    s.Initialize();
    s.Socket();
    s.Bind();
    s.Listen();
    while(1)
    {
        s.Accept();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted does not compile. For example, you've got a destructor (`~Server`) outside of a class definition.

Comment: strlen goes in an infinite loop ifyou forget to *escape* the string with \0 on the end. Also, have you tried using select()? Using that you can wait till you have received some data. On a TCP socket recv() will return as much as the supplied buffer can hold

Comment: Another problem (other than the one by Marlon): HandleConnection() uses `new` without `delete`. Then again, there's no reason you need to `new` here. You could use a stack variable instead.

Comment: @Antwan: not precisely infinite - there's usually a zero byte somewhere in memory that stops it from reading any further.  But you're right - the OP is invoking ill-defined or undefined behaviour with the use of `strlen()` in that context.

Comment: @Antwan: No, `recv` will block until it receives some data or the socket is closed.  If it receives less data than you asked for, it will return a short read instead of blocking until you get as much data as you asked for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite the destructor problem pointed by [@Billy ONeal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82320/billy-oneal), you're doing `recv()` in a loop, but each time you're overwriting the received buffer. I believe you want something like this:

```
// Pass buffer and its real size. This function takes care of NULL termination.
size_t Recv(char* buffer, size_t size) {
    size_t total = 0, n = 0;
    while((n = ::recv(remoteSocket, buffer+total, size-total-1, 0)) > 0) {
        total += n;
    }
    buffer[total] = 0;
    return total;
}

int main() {
    char buffer[128];
    // Connect or whatever (and set your global remoteSocket)
    Recv(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    cout << buffer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `if (total > 0) buffer[total - 1] = 0;`?

Comment: He is overwriting the received buffer while calling strlen(buffer) each time in a loop, so each call to strlen(buffer) would get smaller and smaller if the messages get smaller and smaller

Comment: @bstn: The condition makes sense if the socket is **non-blocking**. The `recv` function returns how many bytes it has read. If it read 10 bytes, then we stored 10 bytes into buffer (buffer[0] to buffer[9]), and set the 10th byte to 0. The caller is responsible for passing `buffer size - 1` to this function.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstood,i just post some part of the code,from a Server class,thats why that destructor apears there,but my problem is that if i use sizeof(buffer) for send,it always send 4 bytes

Comment: @vBx the problem that it sends 4 bytes is because you are on a 32-bit machine and pointers are 32-bits long (32-bits = 4 bytes). You have to pass `20` to your Recv function and use it in recv.

Comment: @vBx: I updated my answer to show an example of how to use it. In my previous comment I stated the caller had to pass size-1, but I changed it because your `Recv` is itself responsible for NULL termination. Now you can pass the real size. Marlon explained correctly the problem you had with the buffer size.

Comment: @Mrlon,yes i know every sizeof pointers = 4, and i do pass 20 to the recv function, but send() sends only 4,so how do i modify the send function to send all the data. Despite puting strlen(buffer) it sends all,but doesnt print anything using  jweyrich function...:(

Comment: yes,if i use strlen it send all 11 bytes,but it doesnt print nothing when i receive them ....

Comment: @vBx: that's another issue. The socket operations are blocking by default, and you're doing a loop until `size-1` bytes are received. It will stay in that loop until you receive the exact amount of bytes. If you don't want that, just call `recv` once, or make your socket non-blocking and handle the possible errors.

Comment: @ jweyrich : calling recv once is just what i wanted,i works now. Thanks all for your patience.

Comment: @jweyrich: i want instead of a string to send an array, packet[3] and in the HandleConection i am using a for() loop to print the data in the aaray,but i get 2 strange caracters an the screen,why is that ? if you can help me

Comment: @vBx: despite it being related to the same piece of code, I think it should be posted as a new question as it's a new unrelated problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is this line of code `while((n = ::recv(remoteSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0)) 0)`

You are using `strlen(buffer)` to get the size of the buffer which is incorrect, you should be passing `sizeof(buffer)` to your `Recv` function.

If that is not the problem then it is one of the problems :P

Edit:

As pointed out by Kitsune and Mark, sizeof(buffer) would return 4 or 8 bytes since it is allocated on the heap and is simply a pointer to a block of memory. If you choose to use the stack (`char buffer[20]` instead of `new char[20]`), you could pass sizeof(buffer) to your Recv function. Otherwise, just use a hardcoded 20.

This is what your code should look like:

```
void HandleConnection()
{
    cout << "You are connected !!!" << endl;
    char temp[20]; // <-- now we have an array
    Recv(temp, sizeof(temp)); // <-- sizeof(temp) will give us 20, not 4 anymore
    cout << temp << endl;
}

Recv(char* buffer, size_t buffer_size)
{
    recv(remoteSocket, buffer, buffer_size, 0);
}
```

Comment: sizeof(buffer) is 4 or 8 (32/64b). You will need to put the known size of the buffer. Either pass a size in, locally allocate an array (in tis case sizeof will be the actual size), or use some other type (a vector<char> could work...)

Comment: I think that sizeof(buffer) in that context would simply be 4 (or 8 if 64-bit architecture).  The buffer size would probably need to be passed in from the calling method.  But +1 for spotting the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify how big the buffer that receives the data is - it is not `strlen(buffer)`.

You can use `sizeof(buffer)` if the buffer array is defined locally as an array (not in the parameter list), or if the buffer is a global or file scope array whose definition is visible in the function.  Otherwise, you need to use an extra buffer size parameter that you pass to the `Recv()` function - that is, if the buffer is defined in another function, or if it is dynamically allocated.  (In the code, the array definition is not visible in `Recv()`, so you need to ensure that `Recv()` knows the size somehow - either as an explicit extra argument, or because you wrap the buffer up in an appropriate class that includes a method that tells you how much space is allocated to the buffer it holds.

<s>Of course, the code as shown doesn't compile because `buffer` isn't actually defined or declared anywhere.</s>

Comment: buffer its the function argument

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler: still if i use sizeof(argument), i get 4

Comment: That's because buffer is passed as a pointer, and you're working on a 32-bit machine where the size of a pointer is 4 bytes.  You have to pass the size of the allocated buffer in as a separate argument.  Classically (think C), you'd use `void Recv(char *buffer, size_t buflen);` (although I'd recommend having `Recv()` return a status).  In the call, that extra argument would be 20 (since you allocated 20 bytes for the data).  Or you can use a C++ class that knows how much space is allocated to it, and take the length from that.