# Sending Large Base64 String over TCP Socket

Tags: c++, sockets, go, tcp, base64

I am trying to send a Base64 encoded image from TCP client using GO and TCP server in C++.

Here is the code snippet for C++ Receiver

```
std::string recieve(int bufferSize=1024,const char *eom_flag = "<EOF>"){
char buffer[bufferSize];
std::string output;
int iResult;
char *eom;
do{
    iResult = recv(client, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    //If End OF MESSAGE flag is found.
    eom = strstr(buffer,eom_flag);
    //If socket is waiting , do dot append the json, keep on waiting.
    if(iResult == 0){
        continue;
    }
    output+=buffer;
    //Erase null character, if exist.
    output.erase(std::find(output.begin(), output.end(), '\0'), output.end());
        //is socket connection is broken or end of message is reached.
}while(iResult > -1 and eom == NULL);
//Trim <EOF>
std::size_t eom_pos = output.rfind(eom_flag);
return output.substr(0,eom_pos);}
```

Idea is to receive the message until End of Message is found, thereafter continue to listen for another message on the same TCP connection.

Golang TCP client code snippet.

```
//Making connection
connection, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost"+":"+PortNumber)
if _, err := fmt.Fprintf(connection, B64img+"<EOF>"); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            panic(err)
        }
```

Tried approaches:

- Increasing the buffer size in the C++ receiver.
- Removing the null character from the end of the string in the C++ receiver.

Observations:

- Length of string sent by the client is fixed, while the length of the string after receive function is larger and 
  random. Example: Go client string length is 25243. For the same string, length after receive when i 
  run send and receive in the loop is 25243, 26743, 53092, 41389, 42849.
- On Saving the received string in a file, I see <0x7f> <0x02> character in the string.

I am using winsock2.h for c++ socket.

Comment: `recv` does not necessarily give back as many bytes as will fit in the buffer - the function returns the number of bytes actually returned as its result. You should account for that where you currently do `output+=buffer;`.

Comment: `char buffer[bufferSize];` -- This is not valid C++.  Use `std::vector<char> buffer(bufferSize);`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840535/c-recv-problem  you may have the same problem because you write the information on the same buffer. (you are never sure to have 100% of the message into the buffer when the function returns, so you have to add it to a "full message buffer")

Comment: You may also have another problem: since the message is never totally into the buffer, you may have a truncated "<EOF>" into the buffer so you will never find it (C++  is faster that network so you may hay a function return every 2-3 characters ;)

Comment: Another issue: following the `recv` call, `if (iResult == 0) { continue; }` is wrong. The *only* time you will get a return value of zero is if/when your peer has disconnected. By using `continue`, you'll then just repeat the `recv`, which will simply return 0 again, resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help.@GilHamilton, how do i wait on the same connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating the received data as a C string - a sequence of bytes ending with a 0 byte - which is not correct.

`recv` receives some bytes and puts them in `buffer`. Let's say it received 200 bytes.

You then do `strstr(buffer,eom_flag);`. `strstr` doesn't know that 200 bytes were received. `strstr` starts from the beginning of the buffer, and keeps looking until it finds either , or a 0 byte. There is a chance that it might find a  in the other 824 bytes of the buffer, even though you didn't receive one.

Then you do `output += buffer;`. This also treats the buffer as if it ends with a 0 byte. This will look through the whole buffer (not just the first 200 bytes) to find a 0 byte. It will then add everything up to that point into `output`. Again, it might find a 0 byte in the last 824 bytes of the buffer, and add too much data. It might not find a 0 byte in the buffer at all, and then it will keep on adding extra data from other variables that are stored next to `buffer` in memory. Or it might find a 0 byte in the first 200 bytes, and stop there (but only if you sent a 0 byte).

---

What you should do is pay attention to the number of bytes received (which is `iResult`) and add that many bytes to the output. You could use:

```
output.insert(output.end(), buffer, buffer+iResult);
```

---

Also (as Phillipe Thomassigny has pointed out in a comment), the "" might not be received all at once. You might receive "" separately. You should check whether `output` has an "" instead of checking whether `buffer` has an "". (The performance implications of this are left as an exercise to the reader)

---

By the way, this line doesn't do anything at the moment:

```
output.erase(std::find(output.begin(), output.end(), '\0'), output.end());
```

because '\0' never gets added to `output`, because with `output += buffer;`, a '\0' tells it where to stop adding.